# How to retrieve username from Amazon cognito user pool in android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-mobilehub

I am finding a way to get user name for Amazon Cognito users pool. I am using AWS Android Mobile SDK with AWS Mobile Hub. Created the user and logged in from my app. After logging in, how can i get the username with which i have logged in?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient` to integrate with cognito user pools.  `AWSMobileClient` has the `getUsername` method that will return the signed-in user's username.

See the aws-sdk-android api reference ( available at https://aws-amplify.github.io/aws-sdk-android/docs/reference/) for more information

Answer (score 0):

You can get user name by using this method

```
String getCurrentValue(){
    AuthUser authUser=Amplify.Auth.getCurrentUser();
    Log.e("getCurrentUser", authUser.toString());
    Log.e("getCurrentUser", authUser.getUserId());
    Log.e("getCurrentUser", authUser.getUsername());
    return authUser.getUsername();
}
```

Comment: and after that call get current TextView